# Template Literal Types not working with string concatenation

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to figure out why the code below does not trigger an error on given keys that are concatenated.

I would like all keys of `obj` to follow the pattern: `prop[number]`. Ex: `prop25`, `prop500`.

Most of the declarations work as expected except two, which I believe have something to do with concatenation.

```
type Props = {
  [K: `prop${number}`]: boolean; //[K in number as `prop${K}`]: boolean; OR [K in `prop${K}`]: boolean;
};


const myString = 'a';
const myNumber = 32;

const obj: Props = {
  prop15: true, // works as expected ✔️
  'prop22': true, // works as expected ✔️
  ['prop25']: true, // works as expected ✔️
  [`prop${myNumber}`]: true, // works as expected ✔️
  [`prop${myString}`]: true,  // does not display error ❌
  ['test'+'test']: true, // does not display error ❌
  'pop22': true, // error as expected ✔️
  propA: true, // error as expected ✔️
  anything: 137, // error as expected ✔️
}
```

[Working code in TypeScript Playground.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.0-beta#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgezAZygXigbwFBSgbQGkAuKAAzETABJMA7AVwFsAjCOAXzIF1SWEEAGwgBDOgG4oAeilEoASzpRGrdlBGoKVWoS68o-IaIlQA8gCUChBUq1IdevgOFjx2Dm+zYAxgjrJgKCYQAGVgOEUAc3QoAHIRWLdff0DggDlmNjgYgGYAJk9kgKgEFgArUngkVAwcPEokAEYAVlJwhggAGmkpKAB3BDgAa1QNKAgAD0hvYAgAEyhAFHJAeD-cOIawPLzYtrgO7pl+wZH1VEnp2YWVtfxYjbzm2P12rp6j4dGzqYgZ+aXVvD4Ow0TDpTLsRxQF4HXoDD6ncbfX5XAEEYG0YJhCJ0SKQ6F4Q5zBAQVB0BCBObyZBgQQiEDjOCIbKAGXIbrFZgFYgBqdkk4BPXb7N5EknKclQSnU2n09hMqCsvB3JBbHZQvavQ6ywYI84-S7-NYbACCgo1vS12TGuuRBrwYhAwAAFlFSI0cgB2GEMuVWpH664cLxAA)

I'm testing this code on **TypeScript v4.4.0**

Comment: Looks like a bug for me.

Comment: Please create an issue on github

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't really a bug, although it might be surprising.  It's definitely a concatenation issue.

---

**Concatenation at the type level only happens with template literal types, and only sometimes**

First: concatenation with `+` is not performed at the type level.  `"foo"+"bar"` is of type `string` in TypeScript, not of type `"foobar"`. There was a suggestion a while ago at [microsoft/TypeScript#12940](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12940) to support concatenation with `+`, and people [ask about it](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40336#issuecomment-695811077) from time to time, but it was never implemented.

Second: concatenation with [template literal strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) is only *sometimes* performed at the type level.  Depending on where it's used, `` `${"foo"}${"bar"}` `` will either be `string` or `"foobar"`.  You can get concatenation at the type level with a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) (as implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#40707](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40707)), or if the template literal string is used in a place that contextually expects the concatenated version (as implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#43376](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/43376)).

So that gives us the following behavior:

```
const plus = "foo" + "bar" // string
const tl0 = `${"foo"}${"bar"}` // string
const tl1 = `${"foo"}${"bar"}` as const // "foobar"
const tl2: "foobar" = `${"foo"}${"bar"}` // also "foobar"
```

---

**Excess property checking does not happen with computed keys of type `string`**

TypeScript has [structural subtyping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#starting-out), which means that a value `v` is assignable to a type `T` if `v` contains all the members of `T`.  It doesn't matter if `v` has *more* members:

```
function f(x: { a: string }) {
  console.log(x.a.toUpperCase());
}
const val = { a: "hello", b: 123 };
f(val); // okay
```

From the type system's perspective, excess properties are just fine.

*But*, there's also [excess property checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-6.html#stricter-object-literal-assignment-checks).  When you use an *object literal* directly in a place that expects fewer properties, it's considered a potential bug because you are throwing away information:

```
f({ a: "hello", b: 123 }); // error!
// -----------> ~~~~~~
// Object literal may only specify known properties
```

*But*, excess property checking *does not trigger* for computed properties of type `string`. See [microsoft/TypeScript#36920](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36920); it seems (although nobody has said so explicitly) that this is not a bug, and asking for it to be changed is considered a feature request.  (Also see [this comment on microsoft/TypeScript#42686](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42686#issuecomment-775318496)). So for now, anyway, we have the following behavior:

```
f({ a: "hello", ["B".toLowerCase()]: 123 }) // okay
```

---

Lack of concatenation at the type level + no excess property checking on `string` computed keys leads to the behavior you see here.  But I can see why the following might be surprising:

```
const o: Props = {
  [`prop${myNumber}`]: true, // works as expected ✔️
  [`prop${myString}`]: true,  // does not display error ❌
}
```

The first one doesn't give an error, but for the same reason that the second one doesn't give an error; they are both considered `string`-valued keys, so neither are considered excess properties.  So that first ✔️ is kind of an accident.

If you want the compiler to treat them as template literal types, you can use `const` assertions:

```
const p: Props = {
  [`prop${myNumber}` as const]: true, // works as expected ✔️
  [`prop${myString}` as const]: true, // error as expected ✔️
}
```

and now both ✔️ are legitimate.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.2#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-C6lS7EjZb6hYKZ0FG3x0e55AQqjICwOejAQIgtIQrEMCADLkizLLAcDTjaGz3o+K6vIOMYUMER71v6W47o8+4JHGx6nsSF7XneDqoc+rasNh1haFAeGfgR4IUJCI5HieZ4tJet6wUkQA)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, seems like a bug. Seems like typescript gives up on calculating the exact type of `prop${myString}` when it's used as object key, just pretends it is `string` and calls it a day. Now for some reason such code

```
declare let a: Props
declare let b: Record<string, boolean>
a = b
```

Doesn't produce any errors, seems like this is closer to the core of the bug. If you force TS to calculate the type of the key properly like this though

```
const obj: Props = {
  [`prop${myString}` as const]: true,
}
```

It shows an error. [Sandbox](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.0-beta#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgezAZygXigbwFBSgbQGkAuKAAzETABJMA7AVwFsAjCOAXzIF1SWEEAGwgBDOgG4oAeilEoASzpRGrdlBGoKVWoS68o-IaIlQA8gCUChBUq1IdevgOFjx2Dm%20zYAxgjrJgKCYQAGVgOEUAc3QoAHIRWLdff0DggDlmNjgYgGYAJk9kgKgEFgArUngkVAwcPEokAEYAVlJwhggAGmkpKAB3BDgAa1QNKAgAD0hvYAgAEyhAFHJAeD-cOIawPLzYtrgO7pl%20wZH1VEnp2YWVtfxYjbzm2P12rp6j4dGzqYgZ%20aXVvD4Ow0TDpTLsRxQF4HXoDD6ncbfX5XAEEYG0YJhCJ0SJcBFFYDPPavN5zBAQVB0BCBObyZBgQQiEDjOCIbKAGXIbrFZgFYgBqbkU4BPXb7UnkynUqC0%20mM5nsNlQTl4O5ILY7KHEmEsxVjc4-S7-NYbACCotehwVgwR%20uRRrwYhAwAAFlFSI0cgB2bVW7J6pGG64cLxzH6MuDQYSBESVKjIbCh7zhyMQQIsUjmH6DOYAHgC2Mi3UMLjoAD5sCIYiw3iFnQgGIIFmx1EpfdggA)

But it doesn't seem to work with `'test' + 'test'` case unfortunately